# Nlog.Mongo get connection from appsetting.json

Tags: mongodb, nlog

I'm running a .net core 2.0 app and using NLog Mongo for logging. Theres a way to get the connectionstring to NLog.Mongo from my appsettings file? Documentation says that I can specify a connection name (connectionName) to get from config file (https://github.com/loresoft/NLog.Mongo).

My appsettings.Development.json has the following:

```
  "DatabaseSettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "Database": "myDbName",
    "IsSSL": false
  }
```

nlog.config

```
<target xsi:type="Mongo"
    name="mongoDefault"
    connectionName="DatabaseSettings"
    cappedCollectionSize="26214400">
  <property name="ThreadID" layout="${threadid}" bsonType="Int32" />
  <property name="ThreadName" layout="${threadname}" />
  <property name="ProcessID" layout="${processid}" bsonType="Int32" />
  <property name="ProcessName" layout="${processname:fullName=true}" />
  <property name="UserName" layout="${windows-identity}" />
</target>
```

When I run the app I got the error:

NLog.NLogConfigurationException: Can not resolve MongoDB ConnectionString. Please make sure the ConnectionString property is set

Comment: See also https://github.com/loresoft/NLog.Mongo/issues/21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try again using NLog.Mongo ver. 4.6.0.68

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Mongo/

Should include the following PR:

https://github.com/loresoft/NLog.Mongo/pull/22

**Update NLog.Extension.Logging ver. 1.4.0**

With NLog.Extension.Logging ver. 1.4.0 then you can now use `${configsetting}`

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer

Comment: Thx, worked like a charm. Just a note, it worked using NLog.Appsettings.Standard. But it did not work with NLog.Extensions.Logging

Comment: @Alberto NLog.Extension.Logging ver. 1.4.0 should make `${configsetting}` work (Updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

An alterenative, if you can't update your NLog.Mongo package, before @Rolf Kristensen solution I was usign this code my on Startup.cs (ConfigureServices)

```
string conn = Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings").GetValue<string>("ConnectionString");
string dbName = Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseSettings").GetValue<string>("Database");
var config = NLog.LogManager.Configuration;
var dbTarget = (NLog.Mongo.MongoTarget)config.FindTargetByName("mongoDefault");
dbTarget.ConnectionString = conn;
dbTarget.DatabaseName = dbName;
NLog.LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```